# Distinguishing log entries in wildfly log

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logstash, wildfly

I have such problem: I have several applications running on single wildfly. I want to distinguish (filter, count and so on) log entries somehow. 
In applications I use slf4j.

I've tried to set up MDC fields on application startup (from startup singleton), but wildfly doesn't log it. Is there any way to make MDC visible or any other way to distinguish applications?

Btw, we're using SocketAppender with logstash and elasticsearch - maybe it's important.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By SocketAppender do you mean a log4j appender? Where is it configured?

Comment: Yeah, I mean log4j appender. It's configured in wildfly's standalone.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf

logstash-gelf contains a JBoss7/Wildfly8 module and LogHandler that evaluate MDC and allow you to add static values. You can download http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=biz/paluch/logging/logstash-gelf/1.6.0/logstash-gelf-1.6.0-logging-module.zip and drop it into the modules directory of your WildFly server.

MDC is a good approach in general for web applications. If your applications create threads on their own (MDB, AsyncEJB, Timer/Scheduler) you need to set the MDC before your application processing begins (e. g. on Message for MDB's).

If your applications use loggers from different packages (different logger names), you could create different GELF LogHandlers with attributes that help you to identify the application.
An example config could look like:

```
<custom-handler name="GelfLoggerForApp1" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jboss7.JBoss7GelfLogHandler" module="biz.paluch.logging">
    <level name="INFO" />
    <properties>
        <property name="host" value="udp:localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="12201" />
        <property name="facility" value="YourApp1" />
        <property name="includeFullMdc" value="true" />
    </properties>
</custom-handler>

<custom-handler name="GelfLoggerForApp2" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.jboss7.JBoss7GelfLogHandler" module="biz.paluch.logging">
    <level name="INFO" />
    <properties>
        <property name="host" value="udp:localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="12201" />
        <property name="facility" value="YourApp2" />
        <property name="includeFullMdc" value="true" />
    </properties>
</custom-handler>

...

<logger category="com.app1">
    <handlers>
        <handler name="GelfLoggerForApp1"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>

<logger category="com.app2">
    <handlers>
        <handler name="GelfLoggerForApp2"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Comment: To a pity logstash-gelf isn't an option here, because it only supports UDP, which couldn't be balanced. And also UDP doesn't guarantee message delievery.